# mosfet n-channel high side switching considerations

Tags: mosfet, switches

I know high side switching is normally done with a pchan mosfet but i don't want have to invert my control signal. So i am curious if i want to source 10mA through the 28V rail on a n channel mosfet high side switch as shown, is this implementation kosher? The datasheet says max Vgs 20V so that requirement is met. I realize my source pin is being held at 9.9V and i am cool with that. If i strap a 990 ohm load on the source i get my 10mA sourced from the 28V rail. What am i missing here? Will i violate the package's thermal rating? Am i violating other specs?  Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Your analysis is right. The power would be around 1.8W which is too much for a SOT-23 package. So I would use two transistors. Use a small PMOS for the switching, and use a 2N7002 to pull down the PMOS gate to turn it on. Then you will get the full 28V and not have to worry about power dissipation in the transistor. Hopefully someone will draw the circuit that  goes with this comment and give you a full answer. If nobody else does I should be able to do it later. The polarity in my suggested arrangement is the same as what you are showing now, so that should be no problem. Cheap parts, also.

Comment: isnt it .181W?  P=iv  v is 28-9.9 =18.1  and I = .01A?  package rating is .340W  , thx for the reply

Comment: Yes. I misread the current. I thought it was 100mA. We should run through the full calculation, though. 0.18W * 348 C/W = 62C temperature rise. The max temp is 150C. So you should be OK up to ambient of 90C. Roughly. I think you will get away with it OK. Keep in mind that the voltage at the load will vary a bit. It probably won't be exactly 9.9V. So as long as the variation doesn't cause problems for you, it should work OK.

Comment: The reason I did the calculation is because sometimes max power is specified with unrealistic cooling assumptions. In this case, though, not so.

Comment: Without a load, you are highly dependent on the actual Vgs threshold of that mosfet. As such, your 10mA will have a wide tolerance range on it. Also you have shown the 10mA through the 10K resistor, which is fine, then you added a load. The current sources will be dictated by both and could be A LOT more than 10mA......